# Is there any restriction for the value the SECRET_KEY setting may take in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, security

I know that it can't be empty, but besides that, there is any other restriction? Can I set it with any string value? Is the length of this string significant?

I've seen that there are SECRET_KEY generators, like [this one](http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/), but I prefer not to use it since, despite being unlikely, the provider of this tool could store the key I generated and use it against me. However, maybe there are some restrictions that makes this key generation non trivial and the use of this kind of tools necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SECRET_KEY` must be at least 50 characters long and have at least 5 unique characters, as shown [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/core/checks/security/base.py#L5), or you may get a warning (however, the key will still be usable, it's just fairly weak if it doesn't meet that criteria).

If you want an easy way to generate your own, `django.utils.crypto` provides the [`get_random_string()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/utils/crypto.py#L54) function.